# Magento 2: Is there a Profiler?

Tags: magento2, profiler, magento2-dev-beta

Does Magento 2 have a profiler?  The

```
Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Developer -> Debug
```

panel still exists, but there's no settings for a profiler there.

If Magento 2 does have a profiler, is it configurable via the GUI?

If it's not configurable with the GUI, how do you enable it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To trigger built-in Magento2 profiler, just add a `SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER "html"` to your `.htaccess`. You can also use `"csvfile"` or `"firebug"`. In case of CSV, you'll find it in your var/log.

Comment: I think I also saw somewhere mention about MAGE_PROFILER "firebug", however I couldn't get that working. "html" works fine.

Comment: A problem was reported with "html" (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/850). If it does not work for you on a page, try "csvfile" until the issue is resolved.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/bootstrap.php#L52

Answer (score 12):

**From v2.2.4 and above**

From version 2.2.4 you can now enable/disable Profiler from the CLI :

```
# Enable the profiler.
bin/magento dev:profiler:enable
# Disable the profiler.
bin/magento dev:profiler:disable
```

Source : [Magento 2/Adobe Commerce documentation](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/setup/mage-profiler.html#cli-commands)

**For older versions**

If you are running on a server with nginx (with fastcgi) :

Put this code on the PHP entry point

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_PROFILER  html;
```

Using Magento 2 nginx.conf.sample file config, you would have a node like :

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
    
    # Profiler
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_PROFILER  html;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

By adding the below code to the root folder **index.php** works for me

```
   $_SERVER['MAGE_PROFILER']=1;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: this is the tricky  solution

Comment: worked..thanks :)